# Programmatically using j_security_check

Tags: java, j-security-check

I have page like localhost:7001/MyServlet. I am making a http connection request from like below

```
String url = "http://localhost:7001/MyServlet"
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url); 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

However "MyServlet" is protected by j_security_check. So when I am making my connection , getting redirected to login page.

How to get authenticated and access my url , in one HttpConnection

Note: I use apache common httpclient

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can log in *and* call the server in a single request, unless HTTP BASIC authentication is enabled. While I do not know the details of HTTPClient's API yet, basically you will need to track a session using cookies; POST your login to `/j_security_check`; then access the servlet. (The same basic process works for `/j_acegi_security_check` if using ACEGI Security.)

A nasty wrinkle in Tomcat is that just posting right away to `/j_security_check` gives a 400 "bad request"; its authenticator is rather finicky about state transitions and was clearly not designed with programmatic clients in mind. You need to first access `/loginEntry` (you can throw away the response other than session cookies); *then* post your login information to `/j_security_check`; *then* follow the resulting redirect (back to `/loginEntry` I think) which will actually store your new login information; *finally* post to the desired servlet! NetBeans [#5c3cb7fb60fe](http://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/rev/5c3cb7fb60fe) shows this in action logging in to a Hudson server using Tomcat's container authentication.